# MassTransit - AWS SQS/SNS - add tags to SNS

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

I have a need to configure the `MassTransit` library in a way that I maintain the tags for SNS.

I can see the places to configure the `Tags` for the `SQS Queues` that are created - and that works as expected. However, I need to do a similar thing for `SNS Topics` that `MassTransit` creates.

There is a couple of things I've tried so far, unfortunately, none of them allowed me to create tags on the `SNS` resource.

```
public IBusControl GetServiceBus()
    {
        var serviceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.Host("AmazonRegion", h =>
            {
                    h.Config(
                        new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig
                        {
                            ServiceURL = _configService.AmazonSnsServiceUrl
                            //Tags doesn't seems the be available here
                        });

                    h.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig
                    {
                        ServiceURL = _configService.AmazonSqsServiceUrl
                    });

                    h.AccessKey("AccessKey");
                    h.SecretKey("SecretKey");
            });
            sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("queueName", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<IConsumer<Message>>(_container);
                e.Consumer<IConsumer<Fault<Message>>>(_container);
                e.QueueTags.Add("TestTag", "DEV");
                //Here I can define only Tags for the queue, not for the Topic though
            });
        });
        serviceBus.ConnectSendAuditObservers(_messageAuditStore);
        serviceBus.ConnectConsumeAuditObserver(_messageAuditStore);
        return serviceBus;
    }
```

I tried also do a manual Subscription like that:

```
e.Subscribe<T>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TopicTags.Add("TestTag", "test");
         });
```

But that didn't work too.

I know there is an option to subscribe to pre-created Topics with `MassTransit`, but I feel that is rather a restriction, and I'd like to use the flexibility of `MassTransit` for managing the types.

Is there something I am missing here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure topic tags/attributes, you need to configure the topic topology, which is done by configuring the Publish topology.

For instance, to add a tag for the `Message` type, you would specify:

```
configurator.Publish<Message>(p =>
{
    p.TopicTags.Add("hello", "world");
});
```

Comment: Worked in the newer version. In 6.0.2 that solution didn’t work. Nevertheless i managed to upgrade package and it helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else lands on this page trying to get `QueueTags` to work, I have found that setting it in the manner of the question - via `IAmazonSqsBusFactoryConfigurator.QueueTags` - does not work as of MassTransit 8.0.8.

I have been able to work around this by calling `IAmazonSqsBusFactoryConfigurator.ConnectEndpointConfigurationObserver` with an `IEndpointConfigurationObserver` like the following:

```cs
public void EndpointConfigured<T>(T configurator) where T : IReceiveEndpointConfigurator
{
    if (configurator is not AmazonSqsReceiveEndpointConfiguration sqsConfig)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Cannot add tags to non-SQS endpoint");
    }

    foreach (var (key, value) in _myTags)
    {
        sqsConfig.QueueTags.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

I realise this is more of a comment than an answer but, alas, I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment yet. Seeing as a Google search for `MassTransit "QueueTags" not working` yields only this page, I thought I'd share my findings here nonetheless.